# Physical significance of the complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, intuition, visualization

In case of the given statement below $\arg(z+i) =2π/3$ where $z$ is a complex numbers .

Here what is the physical way of seeing $z+i$, I mean does this represents a vector that joins $-i$ to $z$ or vice versa or something new as a whole ? Please help me to visualise this.

Comment: Are you familiar with the complex plane?

Comment: If you think of complex numbers as vectors in the plane, then $z+i$ is the vector sum of $z$ and $i$.

Comment: @shamim yes I am

Comment: @angina seng I know this but does that means it is -i vector that joins to z vector which has an angle of 2π/3 or i joined to z , I am basically confused here

Comment: You need to understand the definition of argument properly, if you know that then using the complex plane it's intuitively clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any complex number can be viewed as a vector in the Argand plane. If you have a complex number $z = x + iy$, see it as a vector originating at (0, 0) with its head at $(x, y)$.

Let $\alpha = (a, b)$ be any given complex number ($i$ in your case). The complex number $z + \alpha$ is the vector $(x, y)$ originating at $\alpha = (a, b)$, with its head at $(x + a, y + b)$.

The argument of the complex number would be unchanged if its origin is translated.

Comment: thank you for explaining but it would be very greatful of you if yoh could upload the figure of the same thing you said above sir.

Comment: Sure, here you go: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTNRr.png

Comment: thanks again it helped me a lot 